# Oracle xmlagg with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, oracle, sqlalchemy

I have a column aggregation scenario where the result could be longer than 4000 characters, so I am trying to switch from `listagg` to `xmlagg`.

Here's what I have right now that works as expected:

```
func.listagg(aggregator, separator).within_group(*order_by)
```

However, I couldn't find any examples of `xmlagg` in [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html). The following snippet

```
func.rtrim(func.xmlagg(func.xmlelement(e, column, separator)).extract('//text()').getclobval(), separator)
```

results in this error, which is understandable:

> Uncaught error: Neither 'Function' object nor 'Comparator' object has
> an attribute 'extract'

Is the `xmlagg` supported at all in SQLAlchemy? The version I'm using is 1.4.29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the xmlagg supported at all in SQLAlchemy?

Like any other function, it should work with SQLAlchemy.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import func, select
>>>
>>> f1 = func.xmlagg(func.xmlelement("foo_tag", "foo_column_aggregator", 'foo_separator'))
>>>
>>> print(select(f1))
SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement(:xmlelement_1, :xmlelement_2, :xmlelement_3)) AS xmlagg_1
```

Oracle xmlagg function returs Oracle xmltype ( it is not a varchar neither clob type).

In Oracle SQL:

```
SQL> SELECT xmlagg(XMLELEMENT("foo_tag",foo,';'))
  2  FROM
  3  (
  4  SELECT 'A1' AS foo FROM dual
  5  UNION ALL SELECT 'A2' AS foo FROM dual
  6  UNION ALL SELECT 'A3' AS foo FROM dual
  7  )
  8  ;

XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("FOO_TAG",FOO,';'))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<foo_tag>A1;</foo_tag><foo_tag>A2;</foo_tag><foo_tag>A3;</foo_tag>
```

This part `.extract('//text()').getclobval()` are methods for Oracle xmltype. It's more like NOSQL syntax (or Oracle DB support for XML syntax) rather then raw SQL syntax, so it's not supported by SQLAlchemy (meaby there are same extension, but i didn't find one).
In Oracle it will be:

```
 SQL> SELECT xmlagg(XMLELEMENT("foo_tag",foo,';')).extract('//text()').getclobval()
  2  FROM
  3  (
  4  SELECT 'A1' AS foo FROM dual
  5  UNION ALL SELECT 'A2' AS foo FROM dual
  6  UNION ALL SELECT 'A3' AS foo FROM dual
  7  )
  8  ;

XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("FOO_TAG",FOO,';')).EXTRACT('//TEXT()').GETCLOBVAL()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1;A2;A3;
```

Same of your options can be:

1. Live with xml in python (parse xml like this one `<foo_tag>A1;</foo_tag><foo_tag>A2;</foo_tag><foo_tag>A3;</foo_tag>` in Python  )
2. Write a function in Oracle to convert data from XML format - then call it in python.

Meaby something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_from_xmlagg (a_xml IN xmltype) RETURN clob
  2  AS
  3  v_clob clob;
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT xmlcast(a_xml AS clob)
  6  INTO v_clob
  7  FROM dual;
  8  RETURN v_clob;
  9  END;
 10  /

Function created.


SQL> SELECT extract_from_xmlagg(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("foo_tag",foo,';')))
  2  FROM
  3  (
  4  SELECT 'A1' AS foo FROM dual
  5  UNION ALL SELECT 'A2' AS foo FROM dual
  6  UNION ALL SELECT 'A3' AS foo FROM dual
  7  )
  8  ;
EXTRACT_FROM_XMLAGG(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("FOO_TAG",FOO,';')))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1;A2;A3;

SQL>
```

3. Find or write an extension to SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thanks, this got me in the right direction. I can still think of one issue to resolve with xmlelement: it supports `order by` clause, but because the XMLType is not known to SQLAlchemy, it does not seem to have a way to support ordering. Any pointers?

Comment: Never mind, resorted to `literal_column` to get around this issue to achieve ordering.

Comment: Yes, It seems like SQLAlchemy is not support Oracle XMLType. Oracle xmlagg also support `order by` .Meaby you should bypas ORM and write your own SQL for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SQLAlchemy. However, **extract** is a (deprecated) Oracle SQL function. So, you might try wrapping the result from **func.xmlagg** inside a call to **func.extract**. That result might also need to be inside a call to **xmltype.getclobval()**.

```
func.rtrim(func.xmltype(func.extract(func.xmlagg(func.xmlelement(e, column, separator)), '//text()')).getclobval())
```

Comment: Perhaps, and I tried that , too, but there's no getting around `getclobval` — the type returned by the `extract` simply is not something one can chain `getclobval()` on as it's not a property of that object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).